# Web-push notifications without a title don't appear

Tags: java, android, progressive-web-apps, web-push, android-push-notification

The PWA Web-push notifications for Android aren't appearing without a **title** set (body only).

I have a bug that an Android push notification is not multiline. 
All the text is set in the notification's title - no surprises.

Splitting the text is kinda difficult as there are really a lot of options with their own variables and localization.

I've tried to set the text into a body instead of a title as it's done for iOS (working fine), and the notification just won't come!

```java
webPushBuilder = new WebPush.Build()
.addBody(localizedText)
                        .addData(customDictionary);
```

The pushes arrive with title only and with title+body, but body-only ones don't come.

Is there a way to send them without the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found, a title is required to receive a Push notification on Android.

Setting title to `"\n"`, `" "`, `""` won't work either.